# washing machine stops during cycle

Tags: appliances

My whirlpool ultimate care ii washer stops with water in the tub. It WILL drain if I can get the timer to start again. I can usually get it to start again by moving the dial back around, and sometimes a bit past, the place it stopped. The timer makes inconsistent loud and soft/ fast and slow sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific knowledge of this particular model:

Sounds like the timer may need to be replaced.